# Ruby: Struct vs Initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using `Struct` versus defining an `initialize` method ?

I can already see that it involves **less code** and **not raising** when missing an argument:

**Using struct:**

```
class Fruit < Struct.new(:name)
end

> Fruit.new.name
 => nil
> Fruit.new('apple').name
 => "apple"
```

**Using initialize:**

```
class Fruit
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

> Fruit.new.name
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
> Fruit.new('apple').name
 => "apple"
```

What are your thoughts ? Are you using `Struct` frequently in your projects ?

Comment: What's your use case? `Struct` is great for things that don't have a lot of additional logic.

Comment: I just want your thoughts on this when you need to define classes with initializers. Since using `Struct` seems to be "sexier", I would like to know the drop-downs, if any.

Comment: If you have a specific use case, that's an on-topic question. If you just want to generate a discussion about the pros and cons of various implementations, that's not a good fit for the Q&A format.

Comment: `Struct` is not that useful for general case classes, any more than `Hash` is. It has some nice syntax for simple things, but the shortcuts this allows makes it difficult to do other important stuff such as data type validation.

Comment: @NeilSlater good point thx. @CodeGnome actually I use `initializers` a lot in my project right now and didn't know `Struct` before today.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The class (non-struct) has a simpler ancestry tree:

```
>> Fruit.ancestors
=> [Fruit, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

As compared to the struct version:

```
>> Fruit.ancestors
=> [Fruit, #<Class:0x1101c9038>, Struct, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

So, the Struct class could be mistaken for an array (rare, but absolutely could happen)

```
fruit = Fruit.new("yo")
# .. later
fruit.each do |k|
  puts k
end
# outputs: yo
```

So... I use Structs as throw-away data objects. I use "real" classes in my domain and application.

Comment: Interesting! You definitely don't want to use them as `Class` if they don't behave like it then. Thx. I'll see what other people have to say about it and accept the answer accordingly :)

Comment: I think the right idea here is you use `Struct` for simple data containers, as an alternative to passing Hashes around, and use a proper Object when you're actually adding any sort of logic.