# why would you need an "initialize" in ruby class?

Tags: ruby, initialization

I'm new to ruby.

What I don't get is, if some patterns appear repetitively in my code, there should be something I could do to subtract that part and save the matter.

E.g., here is what it looks like now:

```
class Book
  def initialize(title, author)
    @title = title
    @author = author
  end
  def info
    puts [@title, @author]
  end
end
```

What I want the code to look like:

```
class Book(title, author)
  def info
    puts [title, author]
  end
end
```

What reasons I could come up with:

1. initialize gets called every time an object has been created. so if there's something I want to do every time an object is created, initialize is the official way.
2. the initialize indicates how many arguments a constructor would take. without which it would take 0.

But it still looks unnecessary to me. Is it possible that I could alter the syntax to look like the second one instead of having to do the initialization every time I create a Class, if I have nothing special to execute upon construction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Struct`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Struct.html) exists for exactly this:

```
Book = Struct.new(:title, :author)

book = Book.new('Fear & Trembling', 'Søren Kierkegaard')
book.title   #=> "Fear & Trembling"
book.author  #=> "Søren Kierkegaard"
```

You can add new methods to Book by instead passing it a block:

```
Book = Struct.new(:title, :author) do
  def info
    [title, author]
  end
end

book = Book.new('Zur Genealogie der Moral', 'Friedrich Nietzsche')
book.info  #=> ["Zur Genealogie der Moral", "Friedrich Nietzsche"]
```

or by subclassing:

```
class Book < Struct.new(:title, :author)
  def info
    [title, author]
  end
end
```

For even more functionality in building classes with attributes, have a look at [Virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus).

Answer (score 2):

A class is not a method therefore it does not accept parameters.  The point of initialize is to do any kind of up front work when you newly create an object.  For example:

```
book = Book.new('A Tale of Two Cities', 'Charles Dickens')
  #=> #<Book:0x007f9f5a8933d8 @title="A Tale of Two Cities", @author="Charles Dickens">
```

If you add an `attr_accessor` to the class you can get access to each of those instance variables like so:

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title, :author
  def initialize(title, author)
    @title = title
    @author = author
  end
  def info
    puts [@title, @author]
  end
end  

book.title 
  #=> "A Tale of Two Cities" 
book.author
  #=> "Charles Dickens"
```

Comment: Is it possible that I could alter the syntax to look like the second one instead of having to do the initialization every time I create a Class, if I have nothing special to execute upon construction?

Comment: With a struct, yes: `Book = Struct.new(:title, :author) do; def info; puts "#{title}"; end; end`

Comment: Then why don't I see people using it this way? Is it just customs or are there any other special things about the original Class?

Comment: found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492357/ruby-struct-vs-initialize

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: if you just want a simple wrapper of attributes (i.e. no fancy methods) consider using something like an OpenStruct or a Hash.

That being said, here's some metaprogramming for creating the simple sort of class you described.

```
def simple_class *attrs
  klass = Class.new
  klass.class_eval do
    define_method('initialize') do |*args|
      if args.size != attrs.size
        raise ArgumentError.new("wrong number of arguments (#{args.size} for #{attrs.size})")
      end

      attrs.zip(args).each do |att, arg|
        instance_variable_set("@#{att}", arg)
      end
    end

    define_method('info') do
      attrs.map { |att| instance_variable_get("@#{att}") }
    end
  end

  klass
end

Book = simple_class(:title, :author)

b = Book.new("A BOOK", "ME")
puts b.info
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't alter the inherent Ruby language to do what you're suggesting. However, since the language is so flexible, you *could* define a method which behaves essentially as you describe, e.g.

```
def new_class(class_name, *class_args)
  # insert Ruby metaprogramming code here
end

new_class(:Book, :title, :author) do
  def info
    puts [title, author]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: So I **could** define a new_class like above (I assume it behaves exactly like the Class?). But why don't I see people using it this way?

Comment: No, `new_class` would be a method, not a class. However, if you called `new_class` as I showed, then as a result of executing that method, the class `Book` would be defined as you requested. That is, `Book` would be defined with an `initialization` method taking `title` and `author` as parameters.  As to why people don't do this, I think it's because they prefer the language as it is and/or want to use the idiomatic approach.